# Referencing another table in T-SQL not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I've been running a query on a large number of servers, and on just three of them (SQL2000, SQL2005 AND SQL2008) the query fails.  I've boiled it down to referencing a table in another DB.

```
SELECT * FROM MASTER.dbo.syslogins AS syslogins
```

Which works on 99% of the servers, but on the three gives:

```
Invalid object name 'MASTER.dbo.syslogins'
```

If I switch to the master DB and run

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.syslogins AS syslogins
```

Then it works.  I've also checked I have permissions by running

```
SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin');
```

Which returns a 1.
So why does referencing the MASTER.dbo.syslogins table fail?

Comment: Does it work if you call MASTER in lower case? ie.SELECT * FROM master.dbo.syslogins

Comment: I can't believe that worked.  Thank you.

Comment: For those servers still stuck with Sql Server 2000... Sql Server 2000 is way past end of life. It no longer gets any patches, even for critical security issues, and hasn't for some time now. Continuing to use it is highly irresponsible. Upgrading those databases is job 1.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn your comment is unhelpful and worthless.  I don't own these systems and my clients have a wide range of reasons for still having legacy SQL versions in place.  There are frequently many expensive reasons that "just upgrade" isn't a viable solution, either on cost or risk, or both.  Most clients with infrastructure this old are well aware of the risks and have long term plans in place, meanwhile business must go on.  Please consider in future if your comments will add value, because "dude that's really old!" adds nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the server is set up with a case sensitive collation. Try

`SELECT * FROM master.dbo.syslogins`